# How to access form data of a http request generated by server while redirection in angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a package for angular 1.5 where I have to make payment.
From "Location A" I am requesting for payment with a callback URL and going on payment server and after completing payment. Payment server is redirecting me on callback URL and posting some **form data**.

Now the problem is how access this **form data** in javascript or angular 1.5?

Comment: As far as I understand, `callback URL` is your url, where payment server will send request with payment data (like payment status, etc.), is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, what you have to do is set `callback URL` to `backend route`, which will listen for `payment server request`, process the data that payment service send and store it in DB, on the frontend you could send request in interval for a 30 second to your backend asking if payment is completed (make use of `$interval`).

Note.
Changed from `setInterval to $interval`. Thanks to @Alon Eitan comment

Comment: Why are you suggesting the OP to use `setInterval` instead of the native angularjs services?

Comment: Sorry, for a two years I've been using `Angular` and im used to use native JS methods

Comment: No, in angularjs's world the OP should use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) for that :)